# Alternative to JspWriter.println()

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jsp-tags, fortify

There is a custom tag which extends TagSupport in my project. There is a StringBuffer `sbfOut` in class level. There is `out` JSPWriter in class level which gets populated like below.

```
out = pageContext.getOut();
```

Then sbfOut gets populated like below

```
sbfOut.append("<INPUT TYPE='text' style='width:25px;' title='month' NAME='month"
                    + name
                    + "' id='month"
                    + name
                    + "' VALUE='"
                    + month
                    + "' size='1' maxlength='2' ");
```

Then after appending string to sbfOut out.println() called

```
out.println(sbfOut.toString());
```

This line of code `out.println()` is flagged as "Privacy violation" issue by Fortify tool as it can print sensitive information.

My question is where do this  `out.println()` prints? On the displayed page or in the console ?

Is there a way we can avoid using this line?

Comment: The displayed page of course. Are you sure that fortify is not confusing your 'out' with System.out ?

Comment: @ramp Fortify being a static tool might be getting confused. But as its displaying in page we cant remove the statement . Do you think changing it to below will resolve the issue."((JspWriter)out).println(sbfOut.toString());"

Comment: I am not sure. I dont have the setup to test it out. You could also try  pageContext.getOut().println(sbfOut.toString()); If nothing works, you will have to open a ticket with Fortify support asking them what it is about.